# Running select command on postgres relational Table containing data in tera bytes

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a relational table in postgres of 3 TB. Now I want to dump its content to a csv file. For doing so I am following the tutorial: http://www.mkyong.com/database/how-to-export-table-data-to-file-csv-postgresql/

My problem is after specifying the file to which the export has to be done and select statement. Postgres shows "Killed". Is it because of the relational table being of 3TB. If yes, then how should I export my data from postgres to another file (txt or csv, etc). If not, then how should I figure out the possible cause of the select command getting Killed.

Comment: is `psql` getting killed or is the server getting killed? does it happen in step 3 of the tutorial?

Comment: @JanusTroelsen The psql gets killed. Yes it happens in step3 of tutorial

Comment: [Try exporting it in chunks](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/psql-crashing-don-t-know-why-tp1919761p1919762.html)

Comment: @JanusTroelsen Thanks for replying but how do I declare a a cursor and then do FETCH 10000 to successively read the rows as needed???

Comment: you can also use LIMIT .. OFFSET: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/queries-limit.html that's easier

Comment: @JanusTroelsen Thanks a lot for the help..but I am not getting as to how should I open the file in append mode \o option as mentioned in the tutorial does not do this. Is there some way by which I may open the file in append mode.

Comment: @JanusTroelsen Also is it possible to set the limit and offset programmatically rather than me doing it manually

Comment: Please show the **exact text** of the error(s) and the command you ran, as well as your *exact PostgreSQL version from `select version()`*

Comment: @CraigRinger Actually server is short of virtual memory..there is just 10GB of virtual memory that it has. My postgreSQL is 9.1. Thanks a lot for replying. Hope you'll help me :)

Comment: @RoseBeck If you update your question with the requested details I might be able to. Show the output of `dmesg` after the error occurs too. **edit your question** to include these details. (You should put exact error text, Pg versions, etc in every question).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Killed` suggests you're running on a system where the out-of-memory killer (OOM killer) is enabled by memory over-commit settings. [This isn't recommended by the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/kernel-resources.html#LINUX-MEMORY-OVERCOMMIT).

If you disable overcommit you'll get a neater 'out of memory' error to the client instead of a sigkill and server re-start.

As for the `COPY` ... are you running `COPY (SELECT ...)` ? Or just `COPY tablename TO ....` ? Try a direct copy without a query, see if that helps.

When diagnosing faults you should be looking at the PostgreSQL error logs (which would tell you more about this problem) and system logs like the kernel logs or `dmesg` output.

When asking questions about PostgreSQL on Stack Overflow **always include the exact server version from `select version()`, the exact command text/code run, the exact unedited text of any error messages, etc.**

Comment: @RoseBeck BTW, this shouldn't really be happening - COPY shouldn't need to consume much memory on the server. So I'm still a bit puzzled about what's going on. I might be able to say more if you provide the logs, full PostgreSQL version, etc.